# Is there a way to know, in client, if the champion I'm about to play is AP oriented or AD oriented?

Tags: league-of-legends

From within the LoL client, is there a way to know if the champion I'm about to play is mostly AP or AD; or do you have to load up lolking or just know it before you lock in?

I often just look at my champions and decide what I want to try on the spot; but when it's a champion that I do not know thoroughly, I won't know before loading in game if it scales on AP or AD. Not really useful to decide my runes!

So is there a way to know, from within the client, if the champion I'm about to play is more oriented AP or AD?

Comment: Not that it helps you *right now*, but once you've played the game enough, you'll just know based on experience. There are, of course, a handful of odd exceptions/item builds, but those are not the norm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a place where you can go to find this information. If you click on the link to Collection and go to the Champions tab, clicking on one of the champions will bring up a page listing their damage type, play-style, and abilities among other things. See below for examples of what this looks like.

[image][image]

Comment: Kha'zix is a good example to show that just because champions deal physical damage doesn't always mean they really on auto attacks. So you really have to pay attention to both damage and style when you look at the champion pages.

Comment: Didn't know the new client had that functionality!

Comment: @Fredy31 The old client also had a more simplistic version of this, with bar charts for "Attack Power", "Ability Power", and "Defense Power". I like the new version much better, since it highlights the champion's relative strengths/weaknesses instead of giving a broad, generic look at vague categories.

Comment: Can you get to this while in champ select though? When I ARAM and don't fully know the champ I go to a browser to look them up since Home, Profile, Collection, etc are not available in champ select.

Comment: @clcto no, this is only available in the main part of the client